# What was the size of the SpaceX team in 2006?

Tags: spacex, history, falcon-1

I know a previous question has been asked for the team in 2008 (first successful launch of the Falcon 1).

However, reading Ashlee Vance' s book on Elon Musk, I came accross this paragraph:

> With that mission aborted, SpaceX ordered major LOX reinforcements
> from Hawaii and prepared for another attempt in mid-December. High
> winds, faulty valves, and other errors thwarted that launch attempt. Before
> another attempt could be made, SpaceX discovered on a Saturday night that
> the rocket’s power distribution systems had started malfunctioning and
> would need new capacitors. On Sunday morning, the rocket was lowered
> and split into its two stages so that a technician could slide in and remove
> the electrical boards. Someone found an electronics supplier that was open
> on Sunday in Minnesota, and off a SpaceX employee flew to get some fresh
> capacitors. By Monday he was in California and testing the parts at
> SpaceX’s headquarters to make sure they passed various heat and vibration
> checks, then on a plane again back to the islands. In under eighty hours, the
> electronics had been returned in working order and installed in the rocket.
> **The dash to the United States and back showed that SpaceX’s thirty-person
> team had real pluck in the face of adversity and inspired everyone on the
> island.**

Does this mean that for the first failed launch of the Falcon 1 (March 2006), the team was only 30 people strong?

Comment: considering the stunning speed that spaceflight (and SpaceX itself) has evolved in the last 20 years, I think it's okay to add the history tag to this question about events of 2006 and a "ragtag team" blowing things up and on a good day [scaring cows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HXdjxPY2j_0)

Comment: Yes 100% agree! For more context, I'm researching a bit on the topic of major accomplishment / technological breakthroughts and "small teams". I already have examples of huge companies with still tiny teams at some point (Mojang, Whatsapp, IG, Bubble.io, Tether, Solana, Sublime Text, Notion, Craigslist). But would like to find data points on true tech breakthroughts, esp. hardware wise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceX) they had 160 people in November 2005. My guess would be the "team" in your quote is the team directly supporting the launch who had travelled to the launch site.